# Dynamically Merge a collection to a Word Document

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, templates, ms-word

**Overview:** I have built a simple MVC application that retrieves data from a SQL database, and then stores that information (Name, address, city ect) into a collection. After retrieving the necessary information I want the application to then take that collection of data and pass it into a MS Word mail merge I have created to print Avery envelopes. The application also stores a quantity the user would like to print.

**What I expect to happen:** The application looks at the Word document for the necessary form fields (such as "Address") and then enter the first item in the collection into that form field until the designated quantity is reached (If they entered a quantity of 10 then the first item would be inserted into Word 10 times). It would then do the same for the next item until all items have been placed into to Word Document.

**What is happening:** The application is only entering the first item in my collection to all form fields in Word. So instead of having 1 label for 5 items, I have 5 labels for 1 item.

Here is the code I'm using in my application.

```
        var receptSelection = (PrintEntity)Session[sessionVariableName];
        var model = from n in receptSelection.NameAddress
                    where n.Address != null
                    select n;

        var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        var document = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

        document = application.Documents.Add(Template: @"c:\test\Label3x9v2.0.doc");

        application.Visible = true;

        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            var myNum = 0;

            while (myNum < item.Quantity)
            {

                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field field in document.Fields)
                {

                    if (field.Code.Text.Contains("Name"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(item.Name);
                    }
                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("Address"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(item.Address);
                    }
                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("City"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(item.City);
                    }
                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("State"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(item.State);

                    }
                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("Zip"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(item.Zip);
                    }
                }
                myNum++;
            }
        }
```

I believe the issue has to do with the field.code.text.contains("xxx"). I want to somehow tell it only to see if the first field contains xxx, but having trouble with this.

Any assistance you guys can provide is greatly appreciated. Let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

Regards,

Comment: I haven't programmed with Word for years, but looking logically at your flow, don't you need something at the end of your While to move you to the next set of mail merge fields, or is that taken care of implicitly? There doesn't seem to be a move to next set, or move on to next record set, am I making any sense?

Comment: Well it should go through the fields initially then add 1 to myNum value and repeat.  Once the myNum value equals the quantity model it should stop doing that and then proceed to the next item in the foreach loop. What you're saying does make sense. Just new to C# so I might be wrong with my assumption.

Comment: But myNum doesn't relate in any way to how you're accessing the fields? It's just a counter and you are repeating the same functionality. Like I said, no expect on Word programming, but that's what it looks like.

Comment: Ok. I believe I will need to do some more research on this. Appreciate the information.